# Create image from file programmatically asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am writing project in asp.net C#. I want to create Image programmatically by the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Image image = new Image();
            image.ID = "image11";
            image.ImageUrl = "a.jpg";
            image.ImageAlign = ImageAlign.AbsMiddle;
            image.Visible = true;

        }
```

But nothing is displayed when I run the project.
How to create image from file and display it in the page by writing code in .cs file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created an image control but you have not added it to your form. Write the below code to add the image control to your form.

```
form1.Controls.Add(image);
```

Comment: Thanks!It works. But my aim was to build an image gallery. If I add second image to the panel I lose the previous image. So how to add multiple images to the panel?

Comment: @NurlanKenzhebekov if you want to add multiple images then you should use a datalist and a panel, in datalist a small image appears like an icon but when a person selects that icon display that image in a panel .

Answer (score 1):

At this point, you have just created an image, but you haven't added it to a control or page context to be displayed.  You essentially said

```
int x = 10;
```

but then never did anything with x.

ASP.NET uses composition, so it maintains a collection of controls, with each control also containing a collection of children nodes.  You need to add the image to a container.  For instance, if you want to add the image to a panel named myPanel, it would be

```
myPanel.Controls.Add(image);
```

Check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx).

Comment: Thanks!It works. But my aim was to build an image gallery. If I add second image to the panel I lose the previous image. So how to add multiple images to the panel?

Comment: Make sure you do: image = new Image() for each image.  If you don't you are just change the original image's attributes.  If that is not it, please post code with an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create panel and then you will have to add that image to panel.

```
Panel Panel1= new Panel();
form1.Controls.Add(image);
```